# Deploying a driver fails in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, kmdf

Trying to experiment a bit with KMDF and the echo driver fails to deploy:

`A[13:22:28:862]: An error occured while deploying files to the target machine for test "Driver Preparation": Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.21.27702\debug_nonredist\X64\Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT'..`

Why does it try to find Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT. I have Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT installed with the newer toolset along with 10.0.18362.0 SDK.

I also installed the VS 2017 toolset and now the same error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.21.27702\debug_nonredist\X64\Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT missing.

But it should look into ...\14.16.27012.. instead.

Comment: Have you followed this document: ["Deploying a Driver to a Test Computer"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/deploying-a-driver-to-a-test-computer)? Please check all preparations and steps.

Answer (score 4):

I've been getting the same error. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling also tried 2017 as well. I uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything with no luck. I even tried installing VC141.

I acutally came to your post looking for an answer but on a whim I opened the installer, modified it to install the VC141 stuff which put the files into `Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\debug_nonredist\x64`

VS still complained so i just copied * from Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\debug_nonredist\x64 into Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.21.27702\debug_nonredist\x64 and "things seem to work". It's not much of an answer - but maybe it's good enough?

Comment: I did the same, but still, deploying the driver had problems. I have to install manually.

Comment: This still happens in VS 2019 Community 16.2.3.  Still trying to figure out why VS wants to specifically use V141 when V142 is installed. Haven't found any hard-coded CRT targets anywhere yet.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the result of a bugfix of another issue, as described here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/596096/visual-studio-2019-wdk10.html

The proposed solution worked for me:

> As Administrator, run Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019
> Run the following commands in the VS Developer Command Prompt:
>
> cd /d %VCToolsRedistDir%\debug_nonredist
>
> MKLINK /J x86\Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT x86\Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT
>
> MKLINK /J x64\Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT x64\Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue. Perform the following steps on the **host** computer.

As Administrator, run Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 Run the following commands in the VS Developer Command Prompt:

cd /d %VCToolsRedistDir%\debug_nonredist
MKLINK /J x86\Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT x86\Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT
MKLINK /J x64\Microsoft.VC141.DebugCRT x64\Microsoft.VC142.DebugCRT